# my web aplication using Node.js doesnt load on my localhost

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js, body-parser

my local host isnt loading,
i dont know what to do, i have all libraries installed, i already restarted node, my pc, everything ;c

```
   const express = require('express')
    const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const app = express()
    
    
    //configurações das biblioteca
    //bodyparser
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
        app.use(bodyParser.json)
    // handlebars
    
        app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
        app.set('view engine', handlebars)
    // mongoose
    
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/nomedobanco").then(() => {
            console.log("conectado com sucesso")
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("deu um erro"+err)})
    
    //pasta de arquivos estáticos (como bootsrap)
       //rotas
       app.get('/', (req, res) => {
           res.render('oi')
       })
       app.listen(8080)
```

[localhost not loading[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yat60.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change line from

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json)
```

to

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

You should also fix how handlebars are set

```js
const hbs = handlebars.create({defaultLayout: 'main'});
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
```

Comment: I also added handlebars config which also was wrong

Comment: - C:\Users\Kaynan\Desktop\nodes\app_estudio\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at new View (C:\Users\Kaynan\Desktop\nodes\app_estudio\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
continue -------------------------->

Comment: at Function.render (C:\Users\Kaynan\Desktop\nodes\app_estudio\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Kaynan\Desktop\nodes\app_estudio\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\Kaynan\Desktop\nodes\app_estudio\app.js:60:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Kaynan\Desktop\nodes\app_estudio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Kaynan\Desktop\nodes\app_estudio\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)

Comment: this error appear when i change to: "app.use(bodyParser.json())" and if undo it and still use                                            
const hbs = handlebars.create({defaultLayout: 'main'});
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')


my local host still will only be on eternal loading

Comment: You must have handlebars template called oi.handlebars in views folder as well as layout called main.handlebars in views/layout to make it work. You can read how to use handlebars here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars